# My key property is not a Guid type but a custom reference type with a Guid in it

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I have a domain model, say `Contract` inside this class I have the `Id` property, but this is not a simple `Guid` type, but a `ContractId` type.

```
public class Contract 
{
    public ContractId Id {get; set; }
}
```

and elsewhere in my code:

```
public class ContractId 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public ContractId(){}
    public ContractId(Guid id){ Id=id; }
}
```

Now in my DbContext I need to say what of the properties is my key property.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
.HasKey(k => k.Id)
.ToTable("Contract", "Catalog");
```

Though I haven't compile time error, this will get angry at runtime cause I can't use `ContractId` as a Key property. I have then thought to specify `HasKey(k => k.Id.Id)` since this is a valid Guid but still have a problem. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a [Complex Type](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/making-complex-types-useful.aspx) as `Key` in an entity. Unfourtunaly this is a [limitation of EF](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/390125).The key(s) of your entity has to be primitive type(s) and must be declared it (them) in the same class. Most commonly, the key members are either `int` or `GUID` types, although any primitive type can be used as a key property.